# How do I pass the parameter of valid type<unicode> in aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass the parameter in the configure test event to the start an instance through AWS lambda function.

```
{
  "instances": "i-0f7399b4ca78fc948"
}
```

Got error as follow

```
"errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: i-0f7399b4ca78fc/948, type: <type 'unicode'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>"
```

Comment: Got this error 
while trying to execute got error as follow
"errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: i-0f7399b4ca78fc848, type: <type 'unicode'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.  Good luck!

Comment: The language and actual lambda code would be helpful here, but from the error, I think you are missing some form of parenthesis e.g. (), {} when you are using "Instances" as a value in your code.